# SpringBoot - Mock stateful object created via "new" keyword in integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking, integration-testing

I have an SpringBoot application that consists of a Controller layer and a Service layer.

`MyController` has access to `MyService` via `@Autowired`, while `MyService` has a method that creates a new instance of `MyClass`, which is imported from an external dependency.

```
import externaldependency.MyClass;

@Service
public class MyService {

    public void myMethod() {

        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.doStuff();
        c.doOtherStuff();
        c.doMoreStuff();

    }
}
```

I use `new` to create the instance because `MyClass` holds state; it has several methods that change its state during the execution of `myMethod` until I get the desired result, therefore I shouldn't autowire it nor inject it in the constructor, since that would use a single instance of this class for every call to `myMethod`. I understand that "Prototype" beans exists, but as far as I know, even if I declare `MyClass` as a prototype bean and inject it to `MyService` via `@Autowired`, the service would still use the same instance of `MyClass` during execution, so ultimately I decided to just use `new`.

Recently I've been trying to do an integration test, calling my Controller layer, which in turn will call my Service layer, which in turn will create an instance of `MyClass`. The problem is that one of the many methods of `MyClass` internally calls an external service, which shouldn't be part of the test itself, so I would like to mock this class.

I understand that mocking is done via dependency injection, but in this case I can't do that. Is there an alternative way to mock `MyClass`, or is it simply not possible with this setup? If not, then how could I refactor my code to make mocking possible in this particular case?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

Since `MyClass` holds state, it shouldn't be autowired to the service nor injected via its constructor, but rather new instances should be created as needed. However, whan *can* be autowired is a "factory" which creates these instances:

```
@Component
class MyClassFactory {

    public MyClass getInstance() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

}
```

Therefore, the service becomes:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyClassFactory myClassFactory;

    public void myMethod() {

        // MyClass c = new MyClass();
        MyClass c = myClassFactory.getInstance();

        c.doStuff();
        c.doOtherStuff();
        c.doMoreStuff();

    }

}
```

In practice, using a factory is the same thing as just using `new`; I'm getting a new instance either way. The benefit comes during testing; now I can mock what the factory returns, since the factory is part of Spring's application context:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyClass myClassMock;

    @MockBean
    private MyClassFactory myClassFactoryMock;

    @Test
    public void myTests() {

        // Make a mock of MyClass, replacing the return
        // values of its methods as needed.

        given(
            myClassMock.doStuff()
        ).willReturn(
            "Something useful for testing"
        );

        // Then make a mock of the factory, so that it returns
        // the mock of the class instead of a real instance.

        given(
            myClassFactoryMock.getInstance()
        ).willReturn(
            myClassMock
        );

        // Do the tests as normal.

    }

}
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but at least solved my current problem.